# Evaluating Integral involving exp: $ \int_{- \infty }^{ \infty } {1\over x}\exp\left(-x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I am stuck at the following integral :-

$$ \int_{- \infty }^{ \infty } {1\over x}\exp\left(-x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx$$

Can anybody give me some hint.

and also for this function

$$ \int_{- \infty }^{ \infty } {1\over x}\exp\left(-(x-u)^2-\frac{1}{(x-q)^2}\right)\,dx$$

where $u$ and $q$ are constants.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Notice how the function is odd. Therefore, $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x)=-\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\implies \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)=0$ If we can show that $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to0,\pm\infty}f(x)$ exists, which are where it can diverge, then the integral exists.
As we can plainly see $\lim_{x\to0 \text{or} \pm\infty}$ is $0$.
Therefore the integral converges to $0$.

Comment: The original problem is like this $$ \int_{- \infty }^{ \infty } (1/x)*exp(-((x-u)^2+((1/x)-q)^2))dx$$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ (and the others) is not enough to convergence of the integral. Consider $1/x$.

Comment: If the limits to the singularities EXIST, then the integral exists. For $1/x, \lim_{x\to 0}$ Does not exist, and neither does the integral.

Comment: I got stuck in the integral while calculating the resulting PDF of the two normal distributions PDF. So, Is there any other way through which we can calculate the resulting PDF of two normal distributions.

Answer (score 2):

One hint that might help is to note that the function you are integrating is an odd function, so ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MarkFantini The question actually says "Can anybody give me some hint" so it is an answer.